# Plotting a trigonometric function with confidence interval of the degrees in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, trigonometry, curve, confidence-interval

Hey guys please help me out here..totally new to R and coding software so please bear with me.

Let's say I have 2 sets of variables (in degrees)...

```
data = data.frame(a = c(-75, 7, -78, -56, -67, -82, -2, -34, -49, 83, -38),
b = c(78, -75, 69, 58, 62, 58, -71, 69, 61, -56, 70))
```

Computed the mean values and 95% bootstrap confidence intervals for both a and b (the data is not normally distributed).

```
meana = mean(data$a)
meanb = mean(data$b)

mean.fun <- function (d, i)
{ m <- mean(d[i])
n <- length(i)
v <- (n-1)*var(d[i])/n^2
c(m, v)
}

set.seed(1111)
boota <- boot(data = data$a, mean.fun, R = 1000)
bootcia = boot.ci(boota, type = "all")

set.seed(1112)
bootb <- boot(data = data$b, mean.fun, R = 1000)
bootcib = boot.ci(bootb, type = "all")
```

And then I have this trigonometric function that I want to plot with R, the X axis would be in degrees from -90 to 90, the Y axis would be the response from the function also in -90 to 90 degrees. I installed the package REdaS to have the function `rad2deg` to convert the output from radian to degree. I also plot the data point = x = meana and y = meanb on the graph.

```
library(REdaS)

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-90,90)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x){
    rad2deg(-atan(cospi((x-meana)/180)/tanpi(meanb/180)))
  }) + ylim(c(-90,90)) + geom_point(x = meana, y = meanb)
```

With the code above I got this graph:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kplhJ.png .

***So here is my question***, is there a way for me to add the boostrap CI on this plot I already have(both for the data point and the curve)? I want to see something like a shaded circle area around the data point and a shaded upper/lower area along the curve as a representation of the confidence interval.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a function called `stat_summary()` in the `ggplot2` package. This calculates and plots summary statistics on your plot according to your mappings. There is a `mean_cl_boot()` function which can be used in that function. 
Read up on this using ?stat_summary.

Comment: I'll investigate this right away, thanks!!

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question a little bit, what I am trying to know is if there's a way to be able to plot the 95% CI area of the curve based on 95%CI of the coefficients in the known function (mean of a and b, not the mean response [y] on the predictor [x] in a regression model scenario), sorry I don't know if I'm making this question more complicated...

Comment: I am not sure if I am following, but `stat_summary()` can take predefined values, if you read the documentation you can provide it with a `ymin` `ymax`. Otherwise constructing another column on you df that has these values, you could then plot them using `geom_point()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional comment!!